# KendoUI Datasource Schema.Errors not firing when the server returns 400

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

When the server returns 200 my schema.errors function is called with the server response as a parameter so that I can look through the response and return any found errors. However, my server returns code 400 when there is an error and it seems that kendo fails when it detects a 400 prior to calling my errors function. Is this behavior intentional? Is there a way to make the kendo error handling function work as expected on http codes other than 200?

```
          dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                  dataType:'json',
                  url:'/contents'
                },
                create: {
                  dataType:'json',
                  type:'POST',
                  url:'/contents'
                },
            },
            schema: {
                errors: function(response) {
                    console.log('check error', response);
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: 200 is **not** an error. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

Comment: @RickS - Yes, this is why I'm so confused as to why the method for error handling in the Kendo datasource only works on response 200

Comment: Have you run fiddler to verify what response you're getting from the server?